# Return simple string to html form

Tags: javascript, html, string, meteor, return

this is my java script code...

```
if(vText != "" && vGerätenummer != "") {
        Tasks.insert({
          text: vText,
          gerätename: vGerätenummer,
          createdAt: vDatetime // current time
        });
      } else {
        Template.addObjects.helpers({
          'notification': function(){
            return "Bitte beide ausfüllen!";
          }
      })
}
```

I want only to return the String "Bitte beide ausfüllen" but when i going into the else clause there will no return in the html.

```
<template name="addObjects">
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="text" placeholder="Text" >
            <input type="text" name="gerätenummer" placeholder="Gerätenummer" >
            <input type="submit" value="Add Objects">
            <a>{{notification}}</a>
        </div>
    </form>
</template>
```

Thank you...

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Comment: Your logic is very weird. Why would you want to define a helper only if a certain condition is achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use a session variable (http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/session) in your `else` block. E.g.

```
else {
        Session.set("notify", "true");
      })
```

then in your helper, defined outside the `if` block, do something like

```
Template.addObjects.helpers({
          'notification': function(){
            if (Session.get("notify") === "true"){
                return "Bitte beide ausfüllen!";
            }
          }});
```